# how to use spring storedprocedure with spring data repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

Can someone explain whether it is possible to use spring stored procedure with spring crud repository or paging repository, at least for data fetch part?

I am trying to integrate existing code which uses spring stored procedure with spring repository. but, I don't want to use JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Stored Procedure in Spring Data JPA like below

First Declare the Stored Procedure in Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
   @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "proc_with_input", 
                              procedureName = "pkg.proc_with_input",
                              parameters = {
                                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "inputParam", type = String.class)
                              }),
   @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "proc_with_input_output", 
                              procedureName = "pkg.proc_with_input_output",
                              parameters = {
                                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "inputParam", type = String.class),
                                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "outputParam", type = String.class)
                              })
})
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
    // Table properties 

    // Setters and Getters
}
```

The call the procs in JPA reporsitory interface like below.

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends CrudRepository<MyTable, Long> {

    @Procedure(name = "proc_with_input")
    public void inOnlyTest(@Param("inputParam") String inputParam);

    @Procedure(name = "proc_with_input_output")
    public String inAndOutTest(@Param("inputParam") String inputParam);
 }
```

Comment: The OP does not want to use JPA

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Spring Data module that works directly with jdbc without JPA.

But there is an open source project https://github.com/jirutka/spring-data-jdbc-repository that tries that, although it seems somewhat stagnant. Since you actually create subclasses, it should be able to add/override methods with ones that use stored procedure / jdbc template, since all you should need for this is a DataSource.